# Disable boot from CD/DVD

Tags: startup

Is there a way to disable the boot from CD/DVD? I don't want to disable it permanently, just when it automatically checks on boot for the presence of a CD/DVD.

Comment: I would assume that the answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/how-to-set-up-an-imac-not-to-look-for-usb-flash-drive-info-during-boot-up) is applicable in this case